# Pagination with pageview builder flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement pagination with pageview builder, but with little success.

I am trying to load an additional set of pages once the API fetches a fresh set of data.

here is the pageView builder

```
PageView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              controller: pageController,
              itemCount: news.length,
              onPageChanged: (int i) async {
                print("loop ${news[i].id}");
                if (i == news.length - 1) {
                  print("i $i");
                  await _getNewsList(isRefresh: true);
                 
                }
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container();
}),
```

here is the HTTP call

```
  Future<void> _getNewsList({bool isRefresh = false}) async {
    try {
      final snapshot = await getNewsData(toId: toId);
      if (isRefresh == true) {
        setState(() {
          news.addAll(snapshot);
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          news = snapshot;
          _getNewsApiCall = false;
        });
      }
      toId++;
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print("error fetching _fetchUserDepartments");
      
    } catch (_) {
      print("error fetching _fetchUserDepartments");
     
    }
  }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: what is the problem with this code?

Comment: it's not working as expected, the pages don't load

Comment: does the API fetch data but new data is not shown?

Comment: yes, API fetches the data but it does not reflect in the view.

Comment: also, I am looking for proper implementation like the package here - https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh
which does not support page view builder yet.

Comment: don't assign data this way: ``news = snapshot``,  instead use ``news.addAll(snapshot);``

Comment: ok, now it is going into a loop and the entire list is being appended again, instead of just the newly fetched data.

Comment: your logic is wrong btw. Wait for sometime and i'll give a complete example with pull to refresh and load more data. Give me some time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235220/discussion-between-himeshp-and-omi-shah).

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer,in case anyone is looking for

```
try {
      final snapshot = await getNewsData(toId: toId);
      if (isRefresh == true) {
        setState(() {
          news.addAll(snapshot);
        });
      } else {
        news = snapshot;
        setState(() {
          _getNewsApiCall = false;
        });
      }
      toId = toId++;
    }
```